# Spacing between the top of the page and the start of the content

Tags: google-docs

I have a drawing within the header of my document. I've set all of the margins to 0" and I've tried to add the drawing:
[image]

However despite any movement of the drawing, removal of line spacing, etc. I can't get the drawing to become flush with the top of the page. I realize that this may be an issue for most printers (they can't print to the end of the page), but I want to guarantee that the document has content for when the printer starts on the page.

I was able to do this with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) and I got away with this, but I'm trying to convert the document over to Google Docs.